# Using vagrant and homestead for multiple sites and per project installation

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have been using XAMPP for quite a time, and after discovering Laravel and finding out, that I quite like it, I also wanted to use Homestead. The problem I'm having is, that I can't seem to be able to run multiple sites.

I have tried various things, but the main problem currently is, that one project works, while all the others are getting a connection timeout, when trying to access their webpage.

These are the steps I've taken to use Homestead

1. Installing VirtualBox
2. Installing Vagrant
3. Adding homestead with `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`
4. Clonging the repository `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead`
5. Create Homestead.yaml file in the `Homestead` directory with the `bash init.sh` script
6. Create a new project `laravel new projectA`
7. Require homestead `composer require laravel/homestead`
8. Generate Vagrantfile `php vendor/bin/homestead make`
9. Modify the Homestead.yaml to have an IP that ends with 10
10. Create another project `laravel new projectB`
11. Require homestead `composer require laravel/homestead`
12. Generate Vagrantfile `php vendor/bin/homestead make`
13. Modify the Homestead.yaml to have an IP that ends with 11
14. Adding those two sites to the hosts file `sudo nano /etc/hosts` => `xxx.xx.xx.10 projecta.app` & `xxx.xx.xx.11 projectb.app`
15. Starting vagrant from one of the two directories `vagrant up`

Now, I'm having the problem, that only one of the projects is reachable. It's always the one from where I called `vagrant up`. So if I call `vagrant up` from Project A I can access `http://projecta.app` and `http://projectb.app` times out. The same the other way around, sadly.

This is my `vagrant global-status`

```
id       name    provider   state   directory                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------
fc6fadb  default virtualbox running /Users/mknb/work/projectA
```

I thought I would just do another `vagrant up` from the `projectB` directory but that doesn't work of course.

I don't want to use the global Homestead, because Laravel said, that it is possible to have a `per project` installation, so how do I achieve it? Do you need more information?

I didn't modify the `Homestead.yaml` except of the IP and the domainname `homestead.app` => `projecta.app`

It seems like a global installation is fairly easy with Homestead, since I would just have to add more sites to the Homestead.yaml, but as I said I'd like to have a per project installation. Can anybody help?

Starting vagrant from the Homestead directory doesn't work of course.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Homestead, but I do have Vagrant running ubuntu images with multiple sites. Perhaps you should add the vhost configuration to the Homestead.yaml file too. (Example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268411/laravel-homestead-vhost-configuration)). How do you try to connect to the homestead, through localhost:someforwardedport (maybe they forward to the same port?) or directly to their IP addresses with entries in your local hosts file too? (so not on your vagrant instance)

Comment: I have added the entries in sites but Nginx has not enabled so I have to manually enable it. Can you give a way to auto enable it with just adding the entries in yaml file

Answer (score 46, accepted):

By using Homestead in your way, you create a virtual machine for each projects. Therefore, the VirtualBox cannot forward the HTTP request from your host machine for **all** of virtual machine. You can only run one machine (so, one project) each time.

To run multiple projects with Homestead, you can do as follow:

- Clone Homestead `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead`
- Inside the `Homestead` folder, run `bash init.sh`

Edit the `folders` property of `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml` to share your code of both projects with VM:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/pj1
      to: /path/to/project1
    - map: ~/pj2
      to: /path/to/project2
```

Edit the `sites` property of `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml` to make Nginx enable the domain of both site:

```
sites:
    - map: project1.local
      to: /home/vagrant/pj1/public
    - map: project2.local
      to: /home/vagrant/pj2/public
```

Edit your `hosts` file to forward these domain fo localhost

```
127.0.0.1 project1.local
127.0.0.1 project2.local
```

- Run `vagrant up` at the folder that you cloned the Homestead code inside it (which contains the `init.sh` file).

Now, you can run as many project as you want with just one Homestead virtual machine.

Comment: Hi, jeyp, that's what I have done now. Using one global Homestead installation for multiple projetcs. I upvoted and accepted your answer anyway for your effort :p

Comment: I have added the entries in sites but Nginx has not enabled so I have to manually enable it.

Comment: How can I set a different port for each site?

Comment: I'm afraid that the current version of Homestead does not allow to do that config from the configuration file. You have to SSH to the virtual machine and update the Nginx configuration.

Comment: Manually updating the hosts file is no longer required. Homestead is now compatible with the [vagrant-hostsupdater](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater) plugin. Just run `vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater` from the Homestead directory.

Comment: "$ vagrant up --provision" - is needed.

Answer (score 13):

There are some important steps missing in the accepted answer although it helped me lot. I have added those necessary steps. Thanks **@Hieu Le** for answer.

I assume you have correctly installed your fist site as by the instructions of [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#launching-the-vagrant-box). Now you have another laravel site which you want to shift on vagrant. Follow the following steps.

1. `cd` into the directory of new Laravel project which you want to add. I assume you have all laravel files in it and its working using `MAMP` or any non-vagrant solution.
2. run `vagrant init laravel/homestead`. This command will add the necessary `VagrantFile` in this new project.
3. open the directory of your first original project file and open its
   `Homestead.yaml` file in editor.
4. Now follow the steps defined by **@Hieu Le** in accepted answer to
   modify `.yaml` file

   > ```
   > folders:
   >      - map: ~/pj1
   >        to: /path/to/project1
   >      - map: ~/pj2
   >        to: /path/to/project2
   >
   > sites:
   >     - map: project1.local
   >       to: /home/vagrant/pj1/public
   >     - map: project2.local
   >       to: /home/vagrant/pj2/public
   > ```
   >
   > Edit your hosts file to forward these domain fo localhost
   >
   > ```
   > 127.0.0.1 project1.local
   > 127.0.0.1 project2.local
   > ```
5. On terminal `cd` into your first original original project
   directory.
6. Run command `vagrant reload --provision`. This will reload the
   vagrant machine so that the changes which we made in `.yaml` file come in effect. You database of original project will remain intact.
7. Run `vagrant ssh`
8. Run `ls` and make sure you can see the folder of your new project. If its there
   you have configured your new site correctly.
9. Hit the url of new site with addition of `http://` and your are
   DONE.

Comment: Number 2 is an unnecessary and irrelevant step. The only vagrant file you need in a global homstead setup is in the homestead directory.

Answer (score 1):

Like how [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#per-project-installation) says, you can install Homestead directly into your project, require it using this `composer require laravel/homestead --dev` at root directory of each project you have. Now by `make` command you can generate `Vagrantfile` and `Homestead.yaml` file into your project's root directory.

- Mac/Linux:

  ```
  php vendor/bin/homestead make
  ```
- Windows:

  ```
  vendor\bin\homestead make
  ```

On each project root you will have a `Homestead.yaml` file to edit:

- Project-A

  ```
  ip: "192.168.10.10"
  ...
  folders:
      - map: "~/Code/projecta"
        to: "/home/vagrant/projecta"
  sites:
      - map: project.a
        to: "/home/vagrant/projecta/public"
  ```
- Project-B

  ```
  ip: "192.168.10.10"
  ...
  folders:
      - map: "~/Code/projectb"
        to: "/home/vagrant/projectb"
  sites:
      - map: project.b
        to: "/home/vagrant/projectb/public"
  ```

Add this to `/etc/hosts`:

```
    192.168.10.10 project.a
    192.168.10.10 project.b
```

Then you have to cd to each project's root and `vagrant up`.
Now if you `vagrant ssh` from each project, you will have that project in your VM environment.

Comment: OK but does this allow to run both VMs at the time ?

Answer (score 0):

there is a short cut command to proxy the sites you want to add..

without having to messed up your Homestead.yaml file and provision your vagrant box all over again...

This applies to BOTH GLOBAL AND PER PROJECT INSTALLATION

Just Make sure if you are adding another project...

You add it the (whole project) on your Shared Folder 
Declared in your Homestead.yaml

Assuming your shared folder is
`C:/Users/MYACCOUNT/Codes`

Add another project in that Folder
`laravel new homestead.app`

Then

Assuming your are ssh in your Homestead
Type
a.) if your using nginx

`serve homestead.app /home/Vagrant/Code/homestead/public`

b.) if your using hhvm

`serve-hhvm homestead.app /home/Vagrant/Code/homestead/public`

Just change your domain name and path to public folder of your project

Then Edit your etc/hosts file as Administrator

What ever ip address you define in your Homestead.yaml

usually the default is 192.168.10.10

Use it instead of 127.0.0.1

Why? because if you use 127.0.0.1 your url will look like
homestead.app:8000

If you Use the IP address in the Homestead.yaml

`192.168.10.10 homestead.app`

you can access your site without port 8000
and just use homestead.app

This Solution is Much Better than Provision... And is Faster...

This is what i Do

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: First you just map your other project and database in the homestead.yaml file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sp32.png).

Step 2: Create the database you mentioned in the existing workbench connection [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHqH2.png).

Step 3: Mention that database in your project .env file. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEZfV.png)

Step 4: Add another path in your drivers/etc/hosts file and run `homestead reload --provision`. Your problem is solved. :)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pBBg.png).