# Invalid SERVER_NAME in Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, homestead

On my Laravel Homestead configuration file (Homestead.yaml), I'm defining my domain maps as such:

```
sites:
    - map: ~^(?:www\.)?(?<project>.+)$
      to: /home/vagrant/www/\$project/public
```

Thanks to this, I can visit `foo.dev` or `www.foo.dev`, `umbrella.dev` or `www.umbrella.dev` etc., and it always matches appropriate project folder, `/foo/public`, `/umbrella/public` etc.

I find this very convenient solution, but I found one problem with it. When I inspect `$_SERVER` superglobal, I see that it equals to `~^(?:www\.)?(?<project>.+)$` instead of the valid domain after parsing. That's fine most of time, but some projects like [Kirby CMS](https://getkirby.com/) use this value to build URLs.

How can I make SERVER_NAME to be `foo.dev`, `umbrella.dev` etc.?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Laravel homestead, but you can set the server name in your nginx configuration, *right*? Or should homestead allow you to not set up "virtual hosts"?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is maybe some way to do it via Homestead.yaml, couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: Seems like no, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25268662/3000179

Comment: I added the project I need explicitly in Homestead.yaml as temporary solution, but the question is still open.